# what does the following statement means?

Tags: american-english

I am reading an article and meet the following phrase, can anyone let me know what does it mean?

"add an angle to their pitch"

Comment: I am guessing that you are reading about advertising? but you could be reading about yacht design or roof repair. before anyone can categorically help you really need to add some more context to the question. You also need to explain what research you have done that has failed to determine the appropriate meanings of angle and pitch for you.

Comment: @Spagirl it has to be roof repair :) During a proper roof repair the pitch has to be adjusted to a better angle. :D

Comment: @Helmar, my thinking exactly. Concrete roof tiles are designed for a limited range of pitches and leaks can be cause if the roof pitch doesn't suit the design angle of the tiles.

Answer (score 2):

Because of *their* in the phrase, it's almost certainly about a sales pitch. From the relevant Google definitions:

pitch: make a bid to obtain a contract or other business.
"I've been pitching for this account for over a month"

angle: a particular way of approaching or considering an issue or problem.
"discussing the problems from every conceivable angle"

So it means adding a new approach to their bid to win a contract.